# Passing arguments to runnable class in Spring's Taskexecutor

Tags: spring

I have a trouble understanding how to connect all the parts with Taskexecutor.
I have a task I created, BidProposalTask. (a class which implements Runnable)
the task constuctor has one argument, and needs Autowiring for DB access, etc.

I came up with this code for the executor class:

```
public class ExecuteBidProposalTask {

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    private BidProposalTask bidProposalTask;

    public ExecuteBidProposalTask(TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        BidProposalTask bidProposalTask) {
    super();
    this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    this.bidProposalTask = bidProposalTask;
    }

    public void start() {
    taskExecutor.execute(bidProposalTask);
    }

}
```

and the following XML context configuration:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

as I saw in Spring's documentation, I created a TaskExecutor bean, however, the problem is that the BidProposalTask also needs to be injected. it isn't a singleton, I need to create it over and over in the project with different argument for the constructor.

basically the question is how to autowire a non-singleton bean, so it's autowiring will also work ?

This is quite complicated to explain, so I hope you understand my question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your `ExecuteBidProposalTask` class ApplicationContextAware (essentially injecting the application context into the bean). Then you can declare your BidProposalTask bean in your context file and make the `scope="prototype"`. Then in your `start` method in `ExecuteBidProposalTask` you can do: `context.getBean("bidProposalTask");` and pass that to the executor. Since you declared the scope as prototype, a new instance (not a singleton) will be constructed and returned when you request the bean.

Comment: that's sounds interesting, do you have maybe a link, or an example for such an injection ?

Comment: It's pretty easy. Just make ExecuteBidProposalTask implement ApplicationContextAware (see http://blog.imaginea.com/making-a-spring-bean-applicationcontext-aware/) then you can literally call applicationContext.getBean("bidProposalTask"); and as long as the bean is defined like this `<bean id='bidProposalTask' class="your.class.here" scope="prototype"/>` you'll always get a new instance.

Comment: Yes, but how do I provide a variable argument to each instance of bidProposalTask ?

Comment: Have a setter on the class and call it after you get the instance from the context but before you send it to the executor.